# Relationship of "Threadsafe" with "Atomic Operation"

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

From MSDN here ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) you can see that basic types such as int,byte……are all readable/writable atomic. So I wonder since they are all "atomic"：

**What's the relationship between "An atomic operation" and "lock"? In my mind, if an operation is "atomic", we don't need lock anymore because they must be "thread-safe", am I right?**

And anyway, I was told by someone on the website's forum, are they right?

**1) Any reference type is "Atomic Operation".**

**2) Types such as i++ or --i aren't atomic operations（So how can I check which operation is "atomic", which is NOT?)**

I'm always feeling puzzled by these problems....

---

@Daniel Brückner and @keshlam：

It seems that a mixed operation such as ++i (first read/then write) isn't an atomic. However I feel interested in that if I seperate them into two steps like below:

```
//suppose I have "i" defined and assigned a value
void Fun()
{
   if(i==1)
   {
     i=2;
   }
}
```

If the codes above will be called by several threads, and "if" part only reads (atomic step), and "i=2" (another atomic step), so I don't need lock?

Comment: This statement: "Any reference type is 'Atomic Operation'" makes no sense. A type is not an operation.

Comment: when a type is larger than the native register size then "there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement."

Comment: @MitchWheat: What do you mean by "a type is larger than the native register size"?

Answer (score 2):

An atomic operation is one which is inherently uninterruptable -- there is no way for anyone else to see the system in an inconsistent state, only before or after the whole operation.

A single read or write of a primitive value is atomic FOR THAT CORE. It may not be safe if there's code running in other processor cores; values often aren't flushed out of processor cache and made visible to other cores until the operating system explicitly performs that operation. I don't know enough about C# threading to know how much of a risk exists there.

A read-modify-write, which is what we're more often concerned with, often isn't -- which includes the ++ and -- operations. In SOME architectures, there are single instructions with implement an inherently atomic test-and-set, which is a specialized case of read-modify-write that can be used to implement a very lightweight form of threadsafe locking/counting.... but that depends very much on which processor you're running on.

An operation which involves reading and/or changing several primitive values, or which is doing a nontrivial operation upon a value, won't be atomic no matt1er how you slice it. And most real-world tasks above the level of implementing primitive semaphores do involve more than one value that have to be kept synchronized with each other. So while knowing that some operations are atomic is helpful for the simplest case, you will find that this isn't enough once you get above the very lowest level of subroutines. At that point you need to use an explicit lock to keep other threads from interrupting the aggregate operation. Semaphores/locks basically use a primitive atomic as a fence around the more complicated operation, taking advantage of operating system functions to make the second (or later) thread to try to access to lock wait for it *VERY* efficiently (basically, going to sleep until the lock is released, rather than going into a spin loop). This lets you create larger operations that behave atomically, though they have to cooperate with each other to achieve that.

Summary: If you don't *KNOW* something is inherently atomic, always assume that it isn't, and that if it's going to be accessed from more than one thread it had to be protected by a lock. Failing to do so results in garbled values and extremely annoying debugging scenarios. Don't take chances; if in doubt, protect it explicitly.

(And don't forget that having a structure be atomic doesn't ensure that its contents are atomic. I had to debug a case last year where someone was using one of Java's atomic collection types but forgot that the structure they were storing into the collection also had to protect its own contents.)

Comment: Many thanks! According to what you said, it seems that on MSDN, you mean ONLY a variable type such as what is said above like (int, byte……) are thread-safe and atomic in single thread mode with either reading value from it or writing a value into that? Then why does Microsoft make them "atomic"? It's of no use if they cannot work properly in the multiple thread environment……I still cannot understand why MSDN says this?

Answer (score 2):

Data types are not atomic, some operation with them are or can be atomic. Assigning a 32 bit integer variable

```
Int32 foo = 123456789;
```

is, for example, an atomic operation. It will never happen that another thread observes `foo` to be 52501, that is the least significant 16 bits are assigned but not yet the most significant 16 bits. The same is not true for `Int64` - it may happen that another thread sees an assignment operation only partially executed.

Many other operations are not atomic. For example

```
foo++;
```

requires reading, modifying and writing the value and therefore another thread may read and change the value of `foo` after you read it but before your were able to write the updated value back. You can use [`Interlocked.Increment()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to perform this operation atomically and there are methods for a couple of other operations, too.

So in essence what you called atomic data types only guarantees that variable assignments are performed atomically and this is true for primitive data types and references except `Double`, `Decimal`, `Int64`and `UInt64`.

```
void Fun()
{
  if (i == 1)
  {
     i = 2; // I may have any value here because another thread might
            // have assigned a new value after the test i == 1 but
            // before this assignment.
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks!I can change to another interesting problem：If I wrote a method that would be called by several threads, It began with reading a value with a "if" check, and then when it satisfies the certain condition, it will write a new value directly into the variable itself. So don't we need a lock because each step is atomic?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Without a lock it may happen that you read `1`, another thread writes `2` and then inside your `if` block you overwrite `2` with `3` and your thread never notices that the `1` was changed to a `2`.