# What is the real difference between threadsafe and atomic?

Tags: programming-languages

Does thread safe and atomic have the same meaning in all programming languages? Can they be used interchangeably? If I use a lock (eg: threading.Lock in python) before writing and before reading a variable would this make the operation thread safe as well as atomic? Thank you.

Comment: An _atomic_ operation is by definition the smallest operation that can't be divided in steps at the system level. It can be differently interpreted regarding the system level. As an exemple, a CPU flag setting is _atomic_ from a CPU point of view, and for a "wider" level, one inode write could be an _atomic_ operation from a filesystem point of view. Therefore, _atomic_ operations are essential tools for semaphore, signals, interrupt handling, etc. All theses tools are then required to build threadsafe applications, but _threadsafe_ is **NOT** a synonym of atomic.

Comment: As an example, you can do _unsafe_ _atomic_ operations in your code. As i'm not very fluent in English, if anyone can phrases that correctly in an answer, thanks.

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451909/relationship-of-threadsafe-with-atomic-operation) on this subject. I'm not sure the provided answers clearly state the distinction between _atomic_ and _threadsafe_.